# Custom form processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some custom form (user reputation) that doesn't link with any model directly. 
I have several reputation criteria which affects final returation value
Here is code of the form

```
<%= form_tag("/add_reputing",:method => "POST") do%>
<div class="reputing_column">
    <p>
        <b>Your feedback:</b>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= text_area_tag :comment,"",{:class=>"or-form-textarea"} %>
    </p>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit",:class=>"or-button")%>
</div>
<div class="reputing_column">
    <p>
        <b>Recomendation:</b>
    </p>
    <% @criterias.each do |c| %>
    <div class="reputing_row">
        <label><%= c.name%>:</label>
        <div>
            <% (c.rating_from .. c.rating_to).each do |i| %>
            <%= radio_button_tag "reputing_#{c.id}", i%><%= (i<1)? i : "+#{i}"%>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

In controller I need to summirize a values of `"reputing_#{c.id}"` fields. And then add a record to user reputation table.

How it will be better and properly to process data from this form in controller? I tried to google that problem, but found nothing.

Comment: Without any code there's no possible way we can understand your problem and help you.

Answer (score 0):

No answers, so I'll try to clarify the dealing with, as you called them, custom forms.

Here's the form for selecting a preferred color via radio buttons.

```
= form_for :preferences, url: '', method: :post do |f|
    - %w[black blue white green red yellow].each do |color|
        = f.radio_button :color, color
        = f.label :color, color.capitalize, value: color
    = f.submit
```

The cool thing about forms in Rails that **they can be used with or without a model**. If you have an instance variable called `@preferences` then this form will respect that and will call the `color` method on it to determine the "current" color. This color will be selected on the generated form. **If this variable doesn't exist it won't be a big deal.**

In any case, after submitting the form you'll be able to access the selected color via:

```
params[:preferences][:color]
```